# Multilingual Email Greeting

Tags: wordpress, email, message-templates

CiviCRM for WordPress 4.7.15

Problem: Fix the Email Greeting, so it takes advantage of the preferred language and gender fields. I took a look at:

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Recipe+for+German+Name+and+Greetings+Handling

The page to edit the Email Greeting is hidden under **Administration/System Settings/Option Groups - Email Type Greeting Options**

I came up with the following which works nicely when used in a Smarty Message Template.

```
{capture assign=l}{contact.preferred_language}{/capture} 
{capture assign=g}{contact.gender}{/capture} 
{if $l="en_CA"}Dear{else}{if $g="Male"}Cher{else}Chère{/if}{/if} {contact.first_name} {contact.last_name}
```

To test it, one selects the new **Email Greeting** from the drop down on the **Contacts Summary** page in the **Communication Preferences** section. Then clicks Save. At this point, the CiviCRM says.

[image: Error Message]

Any suggestions? I'm considering adding 3 Greetings and updating all 2697 records via SQL.

Comment: In case this is still relevant, make sure that smarty is enabeld as described here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Smarty+in+mail+templates

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit of a hurry at the moment - we use a greeting based on the prefix - maybe it helps:

> {capture assign=c}{contact.communication_style}{/capture}{capture assign=p}{contact.individual_prefix}{/capture}{if $p=="Frau"}Liebe{else}Lieber{/if}{ }{if $c=="Familiar"}{ }{contact.first_name}{else}{$p}{ }{contact.formal_title}{contact.last_name}{/if}

Comment: Are you on 4.7.15? Because in my case, using the greeting with capture commands "crashes" CiviCRM page. Crashes as in it never finishes reloading the page. In the message context the variables are defined. Maybe they are not in the greeting context. Worth a try.

Comment: I tried just contract.preferred_language and just contact.gender and both resulted in a Network Error.

Comment: I just ried it on the sandbox which is on 4.7.17 - seems to work

Comment: I gave up and did it via SQL

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, we have developed a new extension which may help people struggling with many different and or/complex greetings. The extension (including documentation) can be found [here](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.moregreetings).